# Why does input type=search cause extra padding on Webkit(Safari)

Tags: css, safari, webkit

When using an input with `type="search"` why does Safari add a few extra pixels of padding to the left side of the value/placeholder of the field?

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search" />
```

(remember to view in Safari)

```css
.input {
  padding: 8px 20px;
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<div><input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="input" /></div>
<div><input type="search" placeholder="Search" class="input" /></div>
```

Comment: The *reason* it does that, as this question asks, is because Safari was the one that invented input type="search" years before it was standardized and so Apple implemented it however they liked and deemed necessary to fit the macOS (then OS X) look and feel. Maybe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to remove the styling for the `-webkit-search-decoration` pseudo element.

```css
.input {
  padding: 8px 20px;
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}
.input::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<div><input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="input" /></div>
<div><input type="search" placeholder="Search" class="input" /></div>
```